# Kivy buildozer using wrong version of Kivy and KivyMD when packaging for android

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I am using VirtualBox wih Ubuntu 20.04.1 and have installed kivymd version 0.104.2dev0 and kivy version 2.0.0. However, when I run the app on my phone alongside `buildozer android logcat`, it says that the kivy version is `v1.11.1` and kivymd version `v0.104.1`. I think this is what is causing the errors in my app (and hence won't run).

I've already tried putting the specfic versions in the buildozer.spec file, which still didn't work. Any advice would be great! (if you need the full log I can provide it)

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Try deleting the .buildozer directory in your build dir and running again

Comment: Do you mean the buildozer file in the first screenshot or the second screenshot? (edited above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter what version of kivy, kivymd is installed on your system. The version that gets packed with the app is downloaded while packing and it downloads the version specified in `buildozer.spec` file. So what you have to do is in the requirements of your `buildozer.spec` file instead of writing `requirements=python3,kivy` write `requirements=python3,kivy==2.0.0`. This will make sure that v2.0.0 is installed. Also, after specifying this you might have to rebuild your app by deleting `.buildozer` directory present in the directory where you are running buildozer. One thing to notice is that it's `.buildozer` not just `buildozer` and will be present in the directory where you initialized buildozer i.e where `buildozer.spec` file is. You can type `rm -rf .buildozer` in that directory to remove it. After that, you have to rebuild your apk using `buildozer android debug deploy run`

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the right version of Kivymd. I've tried specifying it as: `kivymd==0.104.2.dev0`, `kivymd==0.104.2` and `kivymd==https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip`. All of these return errors that read `No matching distribution found for (kivymd==0.104.2dev0)` (or whatever I inputted in buildozer.spec). Is there any other way to specify the KivyMD version?

Comment: Buildozer use the v0.104.1 of kivymd which is pretty new so I usually don't specify the version of kivymd. Still if you wanna specify you have to specify it like `requirements = kivy, python3, git+https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git@master,.....` You dont have to add kivyms==https://github.com/...

Comment: I entered `git+https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git@master` and it is still using v0.104.1 when building. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you rebuilt it? After entering `git+https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD.git@master` in requirements delete the `.buildozer` directory then run buildozer again.